# How to read new line in a textarea form using bootstrap?

Tags: string, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I´m making a form using twitter-bootstrap

One of them is a form control which supports multiple lines of text

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="resumen" rows="1"></textarea>
```

then I read the contents

```
texto = $('#resumen').val()+'\r\n'
```

for example if user enters into id resumen form:

```
hello world 
hello world again

texto = hello world hello world again
```

How can I read new lines in the form ?

The full string is a line and do not read the 'new lines' added (using enter) by the user.

I would like to read the full string with diferent lines, as the user enter it
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New lines are there, if you read and print that input string in console you will see new lines are coming.

If you want to print that input string in html then replace those new lines by `<br>`,

If you want to play with each line break them into array

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<a href="#!" id="read" onclick="readTextArea()">read</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function readTextArea () {
    var data = $("#textarea").val();
    var dataNlToBr = data.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');
    var dataArray = dataNlToBr .split('<br>');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(dataNlToBr);
    console.log(dataArray);

  }
</script>
```